# c gcc compiler options for pointer arithmetic warning

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I’m using the following flags, but still I m not able to get this warning:

> pointer of type `void *` used in arithmetic

Flags used:

```
-O2 -Werror -Wall -Wno-main -Wno-format-zero-length -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-attributes  -fno-strict-aliasing
```

`-Wpointer-arith` should catch this type of warning, but I’m not able to get this warning:

> pointer of type `void *` used in arithmetic

Which specific cflag should be used to get this warning?

Edit: my mistake, it is there as part of a macro check which is not defined. :( By defining that macro, I’m able to get that error.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Can you provide the source code. By just improving the source code, you will be able to clear the warning.

Comment: Sorry ..its basically part of netbsd..I cannot post the program.

 gcc version : arm--netbsdelf-gcc -v Using built-in specs. Target: arm--netbsdelf Thread model: posix gcc version 4.1.2 20061021 (prerelease) (NetBSD nb3 20061125)

Comment: Can you post a *minimal* code example that exhibits what you see?  What happens when you compile the program in my answer?

Comment: And what about a small code with have the same problem of yours. just put fake variable name, fake function name etc) so it wont be recognizable.

Comment: Trying to come up with a minimal code example is often very educational. We will unlikely be able to help you if we don't have any code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: my mistake, it is there as part of a macro check which is not defined. :( 

By defining that macro , I m able to get that error.

Thanks for your time...and sorry for my ignorance :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  `-Wpointer-arith` should give you a warning as per the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

I have just tried the following program (with intentional error):

```
~/code/samples$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  void * bar;
  void * foo;
  foo = bar + 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I have compiled the program with just the  `-Wpointer-arith` option, and all your options as listed above.  Both attempts threw up the desired warning. I am using gcc version 4.3.4 (Debian 4.3.4-6).:

```
~/code/samples$ gcc -Wpointer-arith foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic
```

and

```
~/code/samples$ gcc -O2 -Werror -Wall -Wno-main -Wno-format-zero-length -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-attributes -fno-strict-aliasing foo.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6: error: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic
```

The compiler does throw up the warning if you give it the 'right' code.  So, I would recommend you examine ***why*** it is you expect this warning.  Maybe the code you're compiling has changed?

One possible clue I can give you: `foo = bar + 1;` in the code above triggers the warning.  But `foo = bar ++;` will not (You get a different warning).  So if your code uses increment (or decrement) operators on pointers, it will probably not trigger the warning.

I know this is not a direct answer, but I hope this helps you focus your investigation.

Comment: What we really want is a warning on ANY pointer arithmetic using "+".  I misread this post and thought that I had found the answer.  But pointer arithmetic is part of the soul of C.  Of course cerr << "PTR" << ("Yipes" + 1); is valid.

Answer (score 2):

With gcc 4.2.1 on OS X, I get this warning:

```
p.c:7: warning: wrong type argument to increment
```

for the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i[] = { 42 };
    void *p = i;
    printf("%p\n", p++);
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it as:

```
$ gcc -Wpointer-arith p.c
```

Can you post your program, or post the result of compiling the above?

Comment: Sorry ..its basically part of netbsd..I cannot post the program.

gcc version :
arm--netbsdelf-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm--netbsdelf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20061021 (prerelease) (NetBSD nb3 20061125)

Comment: my mistake, it is there as part of a macro check which is not defined.

:(