# Can I do arithmetic on void * pointers in C?

Tags: c, void-pointers

is this valid

```
void *p = &X; /* some thing */
p += 12;
```

and if so what does p now point to?
I have (third party)  code that does this (and compiles cleanly) and my guess is that the void * was treated as a char *. My trusty K&R is silent(ish) on the topic

EDIT: My little test app runs fine on gcc 4.1.1 and treats void * as char *. But g++ barfs

I know how to do it properly. I need to know if I have to clean this code base to find all the places its done.

BTW gcc -pedantic throws up a warning

Summary:

The C spec is ambiguous. It says that in terms of representation and use as function parameters void* =char*. But it is silent regarding pointer arithmetic.

- gcc (4) permits it and treats it as
  char *
- g++ refuses it
- gcc -pedantic warns about it
- vs2010 both c and c++
  refuses it

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997751/c-gcc-compiler-options-for-pointer-arithmetic-warning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on compiler. Those that allow it consider sizeof(*(void *)) as 1.

EDIT: it's only for void pointer arithmetic. It would have no sense using in this case steps of sizeof(int) or of 0. The common expectations of someone who uses it would be the smallest possible step.

Comment: What compiler allows for this?  That implies that `sizeof(void) == 1` which is ... not sane.

Comment: Perhaps for small values of 1.

Comment: @Jason, thank you for wasting a few minutes of my day as I sat in my chair helplessly laughing :)

Comment: For later readers: [GCC considers `sizeof void == 1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)

Answer (score 19):

No this is not legal.  A `void*` cannot be arbitrarily incremented.  It needs to be cast to a specific type first.

If you want to increment it by a specific number of bytes then this is the solution I use.

```
p = ((char*)p) + 12;
```

The `char` type is convenient because it has a defined size of 1 byte.

**EDIT**

It's interesting that it runs on gcc with a warning.  I tested on Visual Studio 2010 and verified it does not compile.  My limited understanding of the standard would say that gcc in the error here.  Can you add the following compilation flags

```
-Wall -ansi -pedantic
```

Comment: Visual Studio compiles code as C++ by default, which is why it throws an error.

Comment: -pedantic throws a warning. compiling as c++ fatals it

Comment: @casablanca I'm still mystified as to how incrementing `void*`  could be legal in C at all.  It certainly doesn't seem portable.

Comment: @JaredPar: I am as surprised as you are, and still waiting for a definitive answer on this.

Comment: gcc without `-pedantic` is non-conforming, but then it's documented to be non-conforming. gcc with `-pedantic` conforms in this regard since it issues a warning for the constraint violation (footnote 8, "It may also successfully translate an invalid program"). Where's the error?

Comment: @Steve, i'm still a bit confused here.  Does the increment of `void*` behavior have defined behavior?  I read the C99 spec on this and can't decide if it does or not.  If it does have defined behavior it seems fairly unportable

Comment: @JaredPar: no, I don't think so. I haven't actually checked the text for the increment operator, but certainly the text for the addition operator talks only about pointers to object types, whereas `void` is an incomplete type. So `((void*)p) + 12;` is a breach of language constraints (invalid program). MSVC is therefore correct to reject it, and GCC is correct to give it implementation-defined semantics and compile it with a warning.

Answer (score 13):

To quote from the spec:

> **§6.5.6/2**: For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

A pointer to void is not a pointer to an object type, as per these excerpts:

> **§6.2.5/1**: [...]                                                                                       Types
>   are partitioned into object types (types that fully describe objects), function types (types
>   that describe functions), and incomplete types (types that describe objects but lack
>   information needed to determine their sizes).
>
> **§6.2.5/19**: The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be
>   completed.

Therefore, pointer arithmetic is **not defined** for pointer to void types.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the C spec is not ambiguous on this. I would add that since 6.5.6/2 is part of a "Constraints" section, this is not undefined behavior, but rather a conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic (5.1.1.3/1). In the case of `gcc -pedantic`, only a warning, but a diagnostic nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct.

In the standard ISO C99, section 6.2.5 paragraph 26, it declares that void pointers and character pointers will have the same representation and alignment requirements (paraphrasing).

Comment: It also says in §6.5.6 paragraph 2 that either both operands have arithmetic types or one operand has integer type and the other operand is a pointer to an object type (a pointer to void is not a pointer to an object type). So, arithmetic on a pointer to void is *not* defined.

Comment: @dreamlax: And **not defined** means the compiler can do whatever the hell it wants to, including use an element size of `1`.

Comment: @dreamlax Yes, agreed. I misunderstood footnote 39. In 6.3.2.3 para 1 it says that void * can be converted to/from anything with impunity. Given that it is required to have the same characteristics as char * it seems logical that it would be implicitly converted to a char * by the compiler.  That said I think it is *really* bad practice to manipulate void * in this way.

Comment: @BenL "not defined" does mean that, but this isn't undefined behaviour, it's a breach of language constraints (the motivation is that the restriction is on the types of the operands, not their values; we know it to be a constraint because of the big heading "Constraints" immediately preceding it ;-)). Constraint violation must result in a diagnostic. Which, with `-pedantic`, it does, so no harm. GCC without `-pedantic` is not, and does not claim to be, a standard-confirming C compiler anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the top voted answer for this question

[Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, because it doesn't know its type, therefore can not seek the correct amount of bytes.

Cast it to a type first, i.e. `(int)`.

Comment: If you cast to `int` though then the `+= 12` is essentially interpreted as `+= sizeof(int)*12` in terms of how many bytes were actually added.  This does not seem like the intended behavior.

Comment: @JaredPar Would it work if that pointer did point to an integer though?

Comment: again depends on intent.  If the intent was to move it 12 elements forward then yes.  If the intent was to move it 12 bytes forward then no.  Hard to read the intent from the question but my assumption is that the OP wants no increment 12 bytes.

Comment: Usually it makes sense to cast (void *) to another pointer type, so for instance to (int *) or (char *) or (struct Foo *), or to some implementation dependent integer type, such as (size_t), even though in the latter case the resulting behavior is not standardized in any way.