# C- void pointers

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   int a[2] = {1, 2}; 
   void *ptr = &a; 
   ptr = ptr + sizeof(int); 
   printf("%d", *(int *)ptr); 
   return 0; 
}
```

For this code i am getting 2 as output
But i just read that a=&a[0] ,ie, name of array = base address of array
so why its giving correct output if i wrote void *ptr=&a which is actually putting ptr=&&a[0]
is this undefined behaviour

ps: i am a beginner and posting question for the first time please explain it thoroughly

Edit: Also why it is not working if we use int *ptr ,ie,integer pointer

Comment: `a` means `&a[0]` *only in places where `a` doesn't work*. Otherwise `a` just means `a`. In this case `a` just means `a`.

Comment: `ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);`  throws a compile error.  Performing arithmetic on a void pointer is non-compliant.  (It is allowed only with a GNU extension.)  Then once performed (if allowed by your compiler.), _using_ that pointer would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Unless you are using a compiler that provides extensions, the code you posted would never allow you to build, so running would not be possible.  What compiler (and compiler version) are you using?  Is the code posted _exactly_ the code you are running?

Comment: yes its exactly the same code i am using in gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0 i dont know much abt it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019671/can-i-do-arithmetic-on-void-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 3):

There is only *one* thing wrong here - the void pointer arithmetic is a GCC extension!

```
ptr.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr.c:7:14: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
    7 |    ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);
      |              ^
```

You should use a character pointer instead:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
   int a[2] = {1, 2}; 
   void *ptr = &a; 
   ptr = (char*)ptr + sizeof(int); 
   printf("%d", *(int *)ptr); 
   return 0; 
}
```

The `void` type is not a complete type, hence you cannot perform arithmetic on it.

As for

```
void *ptr = &a;
```

vs

```
void *ptr = a;
```

`&a` would be a *pointer to an array*, i.e. of type `int (*)[2]`, whereas `a`, after type decay, would be pointer to the first element, i.e. of type `int *`. But both of them would point to the same *memory location* and after conversion to `void *` would result the in the exact *same* pointer value.

As for why it does not work for integer pointer - of course it does, but you need to increment it [not by `sizeof(int)` but by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610298/why-does-int-pointer-increment-by-4-rather-than-1).

Comment: But if i use int* pointer in place of char* i am getting a garbage value which is actually resolved by ptr=(int*)ptr+1 why so?

Comment: @ayushtamra https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610311/918959

Answer (score 1):

All of the expressions `a`, `&a` and `&a[0]` will yield the same address<sup>1</sup> - the address of the array is the same as the address of its first element:

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+
   | 2 | a[1]
   +---+
```

The difference is in the types of the expressions.  `a` has type `int [2]`, but unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type `int *` and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element<sup>2</sup>. `&a[0]` has type `int *`, and `&a` has type `int (*)[2]` (pointer to 2-element array of `int`).

This is why it didn't work when you wrote

```
int *ptr = &a; // int * = int (*)[2]
```

The types aren't compatible.  It *would* have worked if you had written

```
int *ptr = a; // int * = int *
```

Again, `a` has type `int [2]`, but unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type `int *` and its value is the address of the first element - in this context, it's identical to writing `&a[0]`.

---

1. Not accounting for any type conversion - on platforms like x86 and x86-64, `int *` and `int (*)[2]` have the same size and representation, but that's not guaranteed everywhere.

   This is important - an array expression is *not* a pointer.  It will be *converted* to a pointer as necessary, but there's no separate pointer object that explicitly points to the first element of the array.