# Why does casting with a pointer require casting on the right side of the assignment (=)?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Correct way:

```
int *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
void *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

Incorrect way:

```
int *x (int *) = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

What is the reason for this syntax? Because the pointer is the one that iterates, shouldn't the casting be to it (so it knows how many bytes to iterate)?

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void *`. You are telling the compiler to treat that `void *` as an `int *` so it goes with the `malloc`.

Comment: Side note: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845)

Comment: You cast the return value of malloc, and then assign the result of the cast to x. The assigned value is the right side of =, ergo, the cast belongs there.

Comment: _so it knows how many bytes to iterate_ Not sure what that means.

Comment: C  *doesn't* require casting of the right side. Anyway the second example is contradictory: `malloc` returns `void*` so why would you cast it to `int*` to assign it to `void *x`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp "so it knows how many bytes to iterate" - sorry, I mean to access say an integer, the pointer would need to know the data type hence casting, thus to get the next int in memory it would go up 4 bytes as apposed to 1 for a char

Comment: Please read Johnny's link. There is lot of information there.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you all. That makes more sense! Of course if anyone has additional info please comment too.

Comment: You've already told the compiler how many bytes because you declare it as `int *x`, so the cast is not relevant to that. Note, you can't iterate a `void *`. [Can I do arithmetic on void \* pointers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019692)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you very much for you in depth answers - you've helped me and a classmate !!

Comment: It's quite simple: A cast is a conversion of a value from one type to another. You want to convert what's on the RHS to the type of variable to which you are assigning on the LHS, so you cast the RHS. (Note that no explicit cast when going from a `void*` to another pointer type and vice-versa, so no explicit cast is needed here, and it should be avoided.)

Comment: The most correct way is `int *x = malloc(5 * sizeof *x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a quibble: The `=` characters in your code indicate initializations, not assignment. The semantics are similar, at least in this case.

A cast on the left side of an assignment would not make sense.

A cast operator takes an operand of some type and yields a value of some (other) type.

It might help to think of a cast operator as something similar to a function call. Let's say you have a function named `convert_value`. It makes sense to write:

```
some_type target_object = convert_value(foo);
```

or

```
some_type target_object;
target_object = convert_value(foo);
```

There's no reasonable way to express that with the function call on the left side of the assignment. The left side denotes an object, not a value; a cast yields a value.

(You can have a cast as *part of* the name on the left side of an expression, but not at the top level.)

And in this particular case, no cast is required. Rather than

```c
int *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

it's best to write:

```c
int *x = malloc(5 * sizeof *x);
```

An assignment or initialization will implicitly convert a `void*` value to the target pointer type, and the `sizeof *x` style means you don't have to repeat the type name (which can be error-prone, especially if the code is modified later).