# Dereferencing void* warnings on Xcode

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, pointer-arithmetic

I'm aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019671/in-c-can-i-do-arithmetic-on-void-pointers) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997751/c-gcc-compiler-options-for-pointer-arithmetic-warning). The element
of novelty in this one is in its focus on Xcode, and in its use of
square brackets to dereference a pointer to void.

The following program compiles with no warning in Xcode 4.5.2, compiles
with a warning on GCC 4.2 and, even though I don't have Visual Studio
right now, I remember that it would consider this a compiler
error, and MSDN and Internet agree.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int x = 24;

    void *xPtr = &x;
    int *xPtr2 = (int *)&xPtr[1];

    printf("%p %p\n", xPtr, xPtr2);
}
```

If I change the third line of the body of main to:

```
int *xPtr2 = (int *)(xPtr + 1);
```

It compiles with no warnings on both GCC and Xcode.

I would like to know how can I turn this silence into warnings or errors, on
GDB and **especially** Xcode/LLVM, including the fact that function main is int but
does not explicitly return any value (By the way I think -Wall does
the trick on GDB).

Comment: xptr[1] !!! how?? xPtr is pointer to a void. not a 2D array.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: I know it's wrong, Xcode doesn't and this troubles me. And yeah, it's not a 2D array, but maybe you meant "two-element array". I think that Visual Studio would have issued an error even if I wrote xPtr[0] though, and I think that is totally awesome.

Comment: because it isnt wrong.. the compiler doesnt know how big the pointer is ... a void[] ~~ void*

Answer (score 0):

that isnt wrong at all...

the compiler doesnt know how big the pointer is ... a void[] ~~ void*
thats why char* used as strings need to be \0-terminated

you cannot turn on a warning for that as it isnt possible to determine a 'size of memory pointer to by a pointer' at compile time

```
void *v = nil;
*v[1] = 0 //invalid

void *v = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
*v[1] = 0 //valid
```

*note typed inline on SO -- sorry for any non-working code

Comment: thank you for your answer. I feel like the compiler always knows how big a pointer is, and I believe it is 4 or 8 bytes in most modern architectures. What it does not know is the size of the pointed area, but this is not an issue at compile time; your answer seem to focus on this aspect, as you show a call to malloc to allocate the required space. I think also Anoop Vaidya mentioned this size in a way; an issue at compile time arise when the pointed type is incomplete or is void, because the compiler is given no size information, and no machine code can be generated.